# How can I use a variable that belongs to rainlab.user plugin in my custom component

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm building a website in October CMS, I installed rainlab.user plugin for user account management. Now I'm currently trying to create my custom component named "UserDetails.php". I am able to get the username in web page using `{{ user.username }}`. But I need to fetch that username in **UserDetails.php**.
How can I do that?
Could you please help me out? Thanks in Advance.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rainlab.user` plugin's `Auth facade` to get current login user details.

> you can use below code

ref: https://tutorialmeta.com/octobercms/october-cms-access-logged-user-rainlab-user-plugin

```
use Auth;

// it will returns the current logged in user
$user = Auth::getUser(); 
if($user) {
    dd($user->username);
}

// further more to check if any user logged in or not you can use 
// it will return true if user is logged in
$loggedIn = Auth::check();
dd($loggedIn);
```

if any doubt please comment.